# feature versioning in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, versioning, features

I've followed below link to implement feature versioning: http://sisharepoint.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/using-the-featureupgrading-event-to-upgrade-features-sharepoint-2010/

I am new to sharepoint and the requirement is to show the versions of features in my site. Is it possible?
I am not able to see the version anywhere in the site. I can see appropriate version in the feature.xml file in feature folder of 14 hive.
Just want to know that is it possible to see the versions of each deploy in sharepoint site also?If yes then where can I see it?

Answer (score 1):

[Vesa "vesku" Juvonen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2011/07/29/webtemplate-training-materials-lab-4-upgrading-existing-sites-with-feature-versioning.aspx) has writtin a nice and detailed article about upgrading features and showing features in a seperate applicationpage.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Remko, really very helpful answer. One query I am having: Is it possible to have track of all the versions of single feature? Yeah there is one way to hold all versions in custom list and make custom web part to show the data but is there any other way? Does share point keep track of old versions?

Comment: Not that u knie off. You have can get the current version and the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Versions will be stored in feature.xml file, in your case you can create a webpart to display the versions of the features, use the below code to get the version of features using c# code,

```
var spFarm = SPFarm.Local; 

System.Version version = spFarm.FeatureDefinitions["YourFeatureNameHere"].Version;
```